# C# - How to serialize and derialize DataSet correctly?

Tags: c#, serialization, datatable, dataset, xml-serialization

I cannot deserialize the serialized dataset correctly if it has dates. The result is the dates are considered as a separate table instead of columns itself. It seems that it is not parsed correctly. How do I fix this?

Here are the variables under inspection after the serialization and deserialization. You can see that the deserializedDataSet.Tables has 2 counts where its original is just 1 count. I printed the table names and shows that the second table was date. Moreover, I can access the date column in the original data set but unable to access in the deserialized version.

[image]

Here is the serialized data of the dataset.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <producttransactionsummary>
    <id>74517</id>
    <branchid>9999</branchid>
    <date xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Month>11</Month>
      <Day>10</Day>
      <Hour>18</Hour>
      <Minute>25</Minute>
      <Second>40</Second>
      <Millisecond>0</Millisecond>
    </date>
  </producttransactionsummary>
  <producttransactionsummary>
    <id>74518</id>
    <branchid>9999</branchid>
    <date xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Month>11</Month>
      <Day>10</Day>
      <Hour>18</Hour>
      <Minute>25</Minute>
      <Second>40</Second>
      <Millisecond>0</Millisecond>
</NewDataSet>
```

Here is the deserialized dataset.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <producttransactionsummary>
    <id>74517</id>
    <branchid>9999</branchid>
    <date>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Month>11</Month>
      <Day>10</Day>
      <Hour>18</Hour>
      <Minute>25</Minute>
      <Second>40</Second>
      <Millisecond>0</Millisecond>
    </date>
  </producttransactionsummary>
  <producttransactionsummary>
    <id>74518</id>
    <branchid>9999</branchid>
    <date>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Month>11</Month>
      <Day>10</Day>
      <Hour>18</Hour>
      <Minute>25</Minute>
      <Second>40</Second>
      <Millisecond>0</Millisecond>
    </date>
  </producttransactionsummary>
</NewDataSet>
```

Here is my current code:

```
public static class Transport
{
    public static MemoryStream Serialize(DataSet dataSet)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        dataSet.WriteXml(memoryStream, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
        dataSet.WriteXml("input.xml");
        memoryStream.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return memoryStream;
    }

    public static DataSet Deserialize(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(stream);
        dataSet.WriteXml("output.xml");
        return dataSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of that date column in your dataset? Is it System.DateTime?

Comment: MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime. I just used the DataTable.Load(DataReader)

Comment: I do expect MySqldateTime to be convertable/castable between  dateTime. If you load that dataReader in a Datatable that already has the datacolumns defined, including one for your datetime as a regular System.dateTime I would expect this to work.

Comment: The data columns have not yet defined prior to loading data from the DataReader.